# C++, предварительное объявление типа, находящегося в пространстве имен

Tags: c++

Рассмотрим код:

**MyClass.hpp:**

```
class Texture;

class MyClass
{
    public:
    void setTexture(Texture *_texture);
    private:
    Texture *texture;
};
```

**MyClass.cpp:**

```
#include <SFML/Graphic.hpp>
#include "MyClass.hpp"

using namespace sf;

void MyClass::setTexture(Texture *_texture)
{
    texture = _texture;
}
```

Следуя хорошему тону, я стараюсь заменять включение одних заголовочных файлов в другие на предварительное объявление, если это, конечно, возможно.

Так как в заголовочном файле я делаю предварительное объявление `class Texture`, то компилятор сообщает о том, что в `MyClass.cpp` идентификатор `Texture` является неоднозначным.

При этом, компилятор запрещает предварительное объявление вида `class sf::Texture`.

Я не совсем понимаю, как правильно сделать предварительное объявление типа, который находится в каком-либо пространстве имен...

Comment: "Следуя хорошему тону, я стараюсь заменять включение одних заголовочных файлов в другие на предварительное объявление" - это откуда вы взяли такую идею "хорошего тона"???

Comment: @AnT, это общепринятая практика. Не включать заголовок с миллионом зависимостей, если нужен только неполный тип. Например, для ссылки или указателя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предварительное объявление

```
namespace sf
{
  class Texture;
}
```

Однако никакого "хорошего тона" в попытках тотального перехода на предварительные объявления я не вижу.

Comment: Такой вариант не работает. Например, для `std::string`.

Comment: @MGNeo: Что такое "не работает"? И сколько раз нужно повторять, что "не работает" в технических контекстах не употребляется?

Comment: `std::string` является `typedef`-ом. Можно ли в таком случае использовать предварительное объявление? И как? Многие вещи в пространствах имен определены через `typedef`-ы, и я не могу придумать, как их аккуратно предварительно объявить в заголовках.

Comment: правильно ли понимаю, что вы не рекомендуете использовать предварительное объявление вместо включения заголовка? Я имею в виду включение одного заголовка внутри другого. То есть, предварительное объявление стоит использовать только тогда, когда это действительно нужно? Например, для разрыва циклических заголовков, когда два класса должны знать о существовании друг-друга.

Comment: @MGNeo: У `typedef` не бывает "предварительного объявления" потому что в нем нет смысла: нет никакой причины избегать *полного* объявления `typedef`. Но "хорошего тона" из этого не получится, а получится скорее плохой тон.

Comment: большое вам спасибо за помощь.